# asp.net linkbutton and jquery modal pop

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, linkbutton

I Have a linkbutton to do some task , when i click the button i need to display the results in modal popup.. 
I created the buttons dynamically in code, and attached the event to it too like this

```
      LinkButton lnkBtn = new LinkButton();
      lnkBtn.CssClass = "lnk";
      lnkBtn.Text = Server.UrlDecode(r.URL);
      lnkBtn.CommandArgument = r.OriginalSentence;
      lnkBtn.Command += new CommandEventHandler(lnkBtn_Command);
```

in the event I have to Download the Html from the url, and display it in modal div tag

```
 private void lnkBtn_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs args)
{
    string URL = ((LinkButton)sender).Text;
    string HtmlDoc = DownloadURL(URL);
    string HighlightedHTML = HtmlDoc.Replace(((LinkButton)sender).CommandArgument, "<span                 style='background-color:red;'>" + ((LinkButton)sender).CommandArgument + "</span>");
    popup.InnerHtml = HighlightedHTML;

    StringBuilder strScript = new StringBuilder();


    strScript.Append("$(" + "\".lnk\"" + ").click(function () {");
    strScript.Append("$(\"#popup\").dialog('open');");
    strScript.Append(" return false; });");



   Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Script", strScript.ToString(), true);


}
```

every thing is done will
the problem that I have to click the button twice, first to fire the event and register the script
the second time to display the modal,
I Need to display the modal from the first click..
Please help

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to place your code that generates the Javascript in a page event like Page_Init. This way it will inject the javascript on each page load, rather than on link click.

Comment: Thanks Alex, Button creation Code is in Page_Load, but I have a loop to generate more than one button, each button should highlight some text, so the dialog should appear after clicking one of the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem
using Webmethod and ajax request

```
[WebMethod]
public static string Highlight1(int _SentenceID)
{
    var QSentence = DocResultsBLL.ResultsList.Find(a => a.OriginalSentenceID == _SentenceID);
    string URL = QSentence.URL;
    string HtmlDoc = DownloadURL(URL);//search.Items[0].Link);
    string HighlightedHTML = HtmlDoc.Replace(QSentence.OriginalSentence, "<span style='background-color:red;'>" + QSentence.OriginalSentence + "</span>");
   // popup.InnerHtml = HighlightedHTML;
    return  HighlightedHTML;

}
```

then I Displayed the Dialog

```
 $(".lnk").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'Google_Results.aspx/Highlight1',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: '{ _SentenceID:'+ $(this).attr('id') +'}', 
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (msg) {
               // alert('Hello');
                document.getElementById("popup").innerHTML = msg.d;
               // $("#popup").html(msg.d);
                $("#popup").dialog("open");
                $("#popup").bPopup({
                    //            speed: 650,
                    //            transition: 'slideIn',
                    //            transitionClose: 'slideBack'
                    //       //    modalColor: 'greenYellow'
                    easing: 'easeOutBack', //uses jQuery easing plugin
                    speed: 450,
                    transition: 'slideDown'
                });
                return false;
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert('error');

            }

        });
        return false;
```

thanks